# How to add Universal Exit in Pine Script v5?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

**In the following strategy I want to take entry 10 minutes once the Exchange opens (0925 hrs) and close all open positions 10 minutes before it closes (1520 hrs). Means the condition checking period is 0925-1520 hrs and Universal Exit (closing all open positions) is at 1520 hrs. I have added some codes but its not working. Can anybody please help me out. Thanks in advance.**

```
//@version=5 strategy("EMA crossover strategy", overlay = true, calc_on_every_tick=true, process_orders_on_close = true)

session_time = input.session("0925-1520", "Session") is_in_session = time(timeframe.period, session_time)

ema10Close = ta.ema(close, 10) ema20Close = ta.ema(close, 20)

longEntryCondition = (is_in_session) and ta.crossover(ema10Close, ema20Close)
longCloseCondition = (is_in_session) and ta.crossunder(ema20Close, ema10Close)

if (longEntryCondition) 
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long) if (longCloseCondition) strategy.close("Long")

shortEntryCondition = (is_in_session) and ta.crossunder(ema10Close , ema20Close) 
shortCloseCondition = (is_in_session) and ta.crossover(ema10Close, ema20Close)

if (shortEntryCondition) 
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short) if (shortCloseCondition) strategy.close("Short")

plot(ema10Close, color = color.new(color.blue, 0), linewidth = 1) plot(ema20Close, color = color.new(color.red, 0), linewidth = 1)
```

Comment: "I have added some codes but its not working". Not working how? What is the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not working because open positions not closing at 1520 hrs.

Comment: I applied your inputs on my other EMA strategy. Universal Exit is not active and there are few slippages as well. For example noticed that trades are also initiated at 0920 hrs (i.e. before my defined time of 0925) and at 0325 hrs (i.e. after my defined time of 1525). Thus trades are not intraday only, they are carried to the next day and squaring off at 0915 hrs nexy day.

Comment: Please read 0325 as 1525.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it was because of the post, but the formatting was incorrect. This would have been part of the problem. I corrected this and also added inputs for your EMAs. This will allow you to quickly change them and see how it affects the strategy. This will plot indicators as well now, and will close all open trades outside of the session time.

```
//@version=5 

strategy("EMA crossover strategy", overlay = true, calc_on_every_tick=true, process_orders_on_close = true)

string session_time = input.session("0925-1520", "Session") 
string offset = input.string('UTC-0', title='Time Zone', 
 options=['UTC-11', 'UTC-10', 'UTC-9', 'UTC-8'
 , 'UTC-7', 'UTC-6', 'UTC-5', 'UTC-4'
 , 'UTC-3', 'UTC-2', 'UTC-1', 'UTC-0'
 , 'UTC+1', 'UTC+2', 'UTC+3', 'UTC+4'
 , 'UTC+5', 'UTC+6', 'UTC+7', 'UTC+8'
 , 'UTC+9', 'UTC+10', 'UTC+11', 'UTC+12'
 , 'UTC+13', 'UTC+14'])

is_in_session = time(timeframe.period, session_time, offset)
int fastLen = input.int(10, 'Fast EMA')
int slowLen = input.int(20, 'Slow EMA')

ema10Close = ta.ema(close, fastLen) 
ema20Close = ta.ema(close, slowLen)

// Long Conditions
bool longEntryCondition = is_in_session and ta.crossover(ema10Close, ema20Close)
bool longCloseCondition = ta.crossunder(ema20Close, ema10Close)

// Short Conditions
bool shortEntryCondition = is_in_session and ta.crossunder(ema10Close , ema20Close) 
bool shortCloseCondition = ta.crossover(ema10Close, ema20Close)

// Strategy 

if longEntryCondition 
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long) 
else if longCloseCondition 
    strategy.close("Long")

if shortEntryCondition 
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
else if shortCloseCondition 
    strategy.close("Short")

if not is_in_session
    strategy.close_all(comment = 'Trading session ended, all positions closed.')

plot(ema10Close, 'Fast EMA', color = color.new(color.blue, 0), linewidth = 1) 
plot(ema20Close, 'Slow EMA', color = color.new(color.red, 0), linewidth = 1)

plotshape(longEntryCondition 
   , title = 'Long'
   , style = shape.triangleup
   , size = size.small
   , location = location.belowbar
   , color = color.new(color.green, 0))

plotshape(shortEntryCondition
   , title = 'Short'
   , style = shape.triangledown
   , size = size.small
   , location = location.abovebar
   , color = color.new(color.fuchsia, 0))
```

Comment: Great help @d1g1talshad0w!! Feel blessed to have people like you!!

Comment: I applied your modifications on my other EMA strategy. Universal Exit is active but there are few slippages. For example noticed that trades are also initiated at 0920 hrs (i.e. before my defined time of 0925) and at 0325 hrs (i.e. after my defined time of 1525). Thus trades are not intraday only, they are carried to the next day and squaring off at 0915 hrs next day. Any help?

Comment: Please read 0325 as 1525

Comment: For Universal Exit you added if not is_in_session
    strategy.close_all(comment = 'Trading session ended, all positions closed.') for strategy. Wanted to know that how can I use these codes in an indicator (v5)? Thanks.